# Which open-source C++ database GUI project should I help with?

Tags: c++, database, qt, open-source, qt4

I am looking for an open-source project involving c++ GUI(s) working with a database.  I have not done it before, and am looking for a way to get my feet wet.  Which can I work on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/:

> SQLite Database browser is a light GUI editor for SQLite databases, built on top of QT. The main goal of the project is to allow non-technical users to create, modify and edit SQLite databases using a set of wizards and a spreadsheet-like interface.

Answer (score 2):

Do a project you can get **involved** in and passionate about.  Hopefully a product you use every day.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you like and feel that you can contribute to.

Answer (score 1):

In my brief experience contributing to an open-source project, I found two points keep me contributing:

- Great people - the other people contributing were fun to collaborate with and hang out with (virtually).
- Project you care about - doesn't really matter which project as long as the its goals are something you want to spend your free time working on.

Answer (score 0):

Sourceforge has a help wanted page: http://sourceforge.net/people/

browse the postings to see if a project is in your expertise or find one that sound interesting...

And let me be the first to say thank you for being willing to contribute your time and knowlede to the open source movement.